# Uploading file using selenium javascript error

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have browse button to browse for the file. After browsing there is a import button which will actually import the file.
I'm able to browse the path using the following code:

```
public static void uploadFiles(String object, String data) {
            try {
                String filemode="";
                Capabilities cap = ((RemoteWebDriver) driver).getCapabilities();
                String browsername = cap.getBrowserName();
                //System.out.println(browsername);
                if (browsername.contains("chrome")){
                     filemode= "Open";
                }
                else if (browsername.contains("firefox")){
                     filemode= "File Upload";
                }
                else if (browsername.contains("explorer")){
                     filemode = "Choose File to Upload";
                }
                String EXE_FILE=DriverScript.EXE_FILENAME;
                String[] command={EXE_FILE,filemode,data};  
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
                Thread.sleep(5000);

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
```

But when I click on the import button after that "JavaScript error (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)" exception is thrown. EXE_FILE is the path to Fileload.exe which is used for browsing

Comment: Please add the html code which specifies the type of tag "input". If the input type is 'file' then the upload can be done by using sendKeys()

Comment: Which browser you are using?

Comment: Input type is file. Then how to do? there is another import button also

Comment: Can you post the entire Exception that you have received? Visit this link - https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=7135, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11060033/selenium-webdriver-error-for-ie which looks like a smiliar issue.

Comment: @automater Is there any reason why you are using `RemoteWebdriver` instead of `WebDriver`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uploading a file using Selenium:

```
WebElement upload = driver.findElement(By.id("identifier of input tag"));
upload.sendKeys("path to file");
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove capability **INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS**  if you're using it in your test code and manually set your IE protected mode settings to be the same for all zones.
It should fix the problem.

Comment: Can you mention how this setting can cause a javascript error?

Comment: @Manali : Please check the below links http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.in/2012/08/youre-doing-it-wrong-protected-mode-and.html     and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278340/nosuchelementexception-is-occurred-during-implementation-of-internetexplorerdriv . Hope that will clear